# Wso2 : Added Oracle DB connection, however getting below errors while starting wso2 service

Tags: oracle, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have added, the below in deployment.toml file

```
[database.shared_db]
type = "oracle"
url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@x.x.x.x:1521/share"
username = "wso2sh"
password = "wso2shar"
driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
validationQuery = "SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"
[database.apim_db]
type = "oracle"
url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@x.x.x.x:1521/apim"
username = "wso2ap"
password = "wso2apim"
driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
validationQuery = "SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"*
```

however getting the below errors:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-03-27 19:00:24,895] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm} - nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: DB error occurred while persisting domain : PRIMARY & tenant id : -1234 Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00257: Archiver error. Connect AS SYSDBA only until resolved.
```

Im unable to understand where exactly is the error, Please help with solutions on how to fix this issue or debug it.

Comment: The error is "ORA-00257: Archiver error. Connect AS SYSDBA only until resolved" which is something you or your DBA will have to look at at the database end.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an Oracle issue at a glance. But the error `org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class` is seen when you have changed the user_store manager configs. Hence try adding the following to the `deployment.toml`.

```ini
[user_store]
type = 'database_unique_id'
```

Comment: I have given the same, however getting same error